# Javascript - Need to un-gray a textbox/dropdown list when a certain radio button is checked

Tags: javascript

I know this problem has been fiddled with before, but since I'm no way a professional, I've been trying and trying to implement these solutions and have not succeeded for 3 days. I'm sorry for a dumb question but could anyone help me out with a working solution. It should be really easy if you know what you're doing :)

http://pastebin.com/hCVVVwF6

I need to make so that if radio button for 'hotel' is set to 'Yes', the dropdown lists 'hotel_pref' and 'hotel_BLA' become active. Otherwise they should be grayed out (in case nothing is checked in 'hotel' or 'No' is checked).

I can understand that I would need to use JavaScript and some people have been suggesting jQuery. I have tried to add some codes to my HTML but nothing seems to change or work at all. Could anyone please do this little thing for me? From that I hope I will be able to implement it to the actual code (this pastebin code is just a simplification).

I'm really looking forward to your help and I really do appreciate it!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: _“It should be really easy if you know what you're doing :)”_ – well then you should see to it that you get yourself to that stage, instead of begging for ready-to-use code here.

Comment: Great comment, I was waiting for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you get used to and understand JavaScript before starting with jQuery. jQuery is just a JavaScript library, not a different language, so JavaScript knowledge is essential when working with jQuery.

In light of this and also due to the simplicity of what you're trying to do, pure JavaScript will suffice for now, as a learning exercise.

Secondly, you need to set a logical default arrangement, for example the "No" radio checked and the two selects disabled. Add `checked` for the radio and `disabled` for the selects:

```
<input type="radio" name="hotel" value="no" checked>No<br>
...
<select name="hotel_pref" size="1" disabled>
...
<select name="hotel_BLA" size="1" disabled>
```

In order to do what you want, you must assign a JavaScript function on the `change` event for your radio buttons, like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="hotel" value="yes" onchange="updateFields(false)">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="hotel" value="no" onchange="updateFields(true)" checked>No<br>
```

What that does is call the function `updateFields` with the parameter `false` when the first radio is clicked and with the parameter `true` when the second radio is clicked. Because they are radios, clicking the second radio button will deselect the first, but the function only gets called for the radio button that gets selected.

After this, you need an easy way to find the selects you need to disable or enable, so you need to add ids:

```
<select name="hotel_pref" id="hotel_pref" size="1" disabled>
...
<select name="hotel_BLA" id="hotel_bla" size="1" disabled>
```

The last step is defining the function, preferably in the `<head>` section of the HTML:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateFields(disabled){
        document.getElementById('hotel_pref').disabled = disabled;
        document.getElementById('hotel_bla').disabled = disabled;
    }
</script>
</head>
```

What this function does is take the `disabled` parameter, find the elements with the matching ids and set their `disabled` attribute accordingly.

That should be it. Since you're a fan of PasteBin, the final result is here: http://pastebin.com/iPe31PGN

I also recommend you go through an interactive JavaScript tutorial, in order to get a basic understanding of what the principles are and how to work with them. I found the tutorials on [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript) to my liking and I found they generally produce good results with interns, but that's just a matter of personal preference.